# How to prove something is a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

The sample space for tossing a coin twice is $\Omega=\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$ and it is given the $\sigma$-field

$\sigma(\Omega)=\{\emptyset,\{HH\},\{TT\},\{HT,TH\},\{HH,TT\},\{HH,HT,TH\},\{HT,TH,TT\},\Omega\}$

We define the functions $X$ and $Y$ as $X(TT)=0, X(HT)=X(TH)=1$ and $X(HH)=2$ and $Y(HT)=Y(HH)=1$ and $Y(TH)=Y(TT)=0$

How would we show that $X$ is a random variable?

The definition of a random variable in my textbook simply states that "a random variable is a function from S into the real numbers" and I don't think that is sufficient for showing $X$ is a random variable.  Would we need to show the event is measurable? If so, how would we do this?

Comment: take any measurable subset of the reals and show that the pre image of this set under your rv is in your sigma algebra

Comment: following the comment above, in this exact case, you can prove that $Z$ is a random variable iff $Z(HT) = Z(TH)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the function must be measurable.  In particular, that means that the preimage of any measurable set must be itself measurable.

To take $X$ for instance: given any measurable set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, all you really care about is whether that set contains $0$, $1$, or $2$.  If $0$ is in the set, then the preimage contains $TT$; if $1$ is in the set, then $HT$ and $TH$ are in the preimage; and finally if $2$ is in the set, then $HH$ is in the preimage.

This shows you that there are only $8$ possible preimages for a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Can you list those possible preimages?  Then you just need to verify that each of those preimages is measurable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Just to make sure I understand correctly.  If we wanted to show something is not a random variable, would taking an event, ex: $\{Y \leq 1/2\}$ and showing that its preimage $\{TH\}$ not being in the sigma-algebra be sufficient?

Comment: @ConfusedGradStudent Note that the preimage is actually $\{TH, TT\}$ -- but yes, the fact that this isn't in the $\sigma$-field would mean $Y$ isn't a measurable function in this case.